# Python typing: How to assert which type from a union of types a value has?

Tags: python, annotations, mypy

In short, I have a function that returns either int or float. The caller function then checks the return-type of the first function and return -1 if float else return the original value since it must be int.

```
# pseudo code for the aforementioned 

def f1(*args, **kwargs) -> int | float: ... 

def f2(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
    ans = f1(...)
    if type(ans) == float:
        return -1
    return ans  # the idea here is that if f1 does not return float, it must return an int which is a valid return for f2
```

My static checker fails with the following error

```
Expression of type "int | float" cannot be assigned to return type "int"
  Type "int | float" cannot be assigned to type "int"
    "float" is incompatible with "int"
```

The error message is very straight forwards, f1 returns either int or float, since f2 expects to return int, it can't return the result of f1 directly. However, (ideally) my if statement guards against the possibility that the result of f1 is float.

Does anyone know of a better way to annotate the following. I am currently using the **type: ignore** flag but I wish not to use this workaround.

Comment: What's your Python version ?

Comment: in this env, it's Python 3.9.13. But I have had the same issue with 3.10.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check with `isinstance`:

```
def f1(*args, **kwargs) -> int | float: ... 

def f2(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
    ans = f1(...)
    if isinstance(ans, float):
        return -1
    # now the typechecker can infer the type of 'ans' as int
    return ans
```

More info in  [Mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html#type-narrowing-expressions)

Comment: This does fix it. Thank you. 

I try to avoid **isinstance** as much as possible as it limits duck-typing, as mentioned on Fluent Python by Luciano Ramalho. But so far this is the only thing that made the error disappear.

In case anyone is wondering; https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/fluent-python-2nd/9781492056348/

Comment: @Dario I'm not sure in what context that statement is made, but in any case, using type() is always going to be more limiting, because it only matches the exact class, and not its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a typecast to assert towards the typechecker that the value is indeed of a particular type:

```
import typing

def f1(*args, **kwargs) -> int | float: ... 

def f2(*args, **kwargs) -> int:
    ans = f1(...)
    if type(ans) == float:
        return -1
    return typing.cast(int, ans)
```